# Improving a SRAM-based memory cell by reducing number of transistors

Tags: transistors, memory, sram

I'm working on [Emulated version](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0A151+112+144+176+144+0+2+5+5%0Aw+176+144+192+144+0%0Aw+112+128+96+128+0%0Aw+112+160+96+160+0%0Aw+192+144+192+208+0%0A151+192+224+256+224+0+2+5+5%0Aw+192+240+96+240+0%0Aw+96+160+96+240+0%0Aw+96+240+64+240+0%0Aw+96+128+64+128+0%0As+0+128+64+128+0+1+false%0As+0+240+64+240+0+1+false%0AR+0+128+-48+128+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AR+0+240+-48+240+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+192+144+272+144+0%0Aw+256+224+272+224+0%0A151+304+128+368+128+0+2+0+5%0A151+304+240+368+240+0+2+5+5%0Aw+272+144+304+112+0%0Aw+272+224+304+256+0%0Aw+304+224+304+208+0%0Aw+304+208+384+128+0%0Aw+384+128+368+128+0%0Aw+304+144+304+160+0%0Aw+304+160+384+240+0%0Aw+384+240+368+240+0%0Aw+384+128+432+128+0%0AM+432+128+512+128+2+2.5%0Ax+469+162+541+165+4+24+Output%0Ax+-6+158+71+161+4+24+Data%5CsIn%0Ax+-31+273+105+276+4+24+Enable%5CsWrite%0A) of a memory cell. It is a volatile single-bit memory.

[image: Memory Cell]

It uses 4 NAND gates to store one bit. I want to connect several of those memory cells together to create one byte of RAM.
Each NAND gate uses 2 transistors, so, in total - it uses 8 transistors. I'm facing a problem because of it. I have to reduce the number of transistors somehow. I tried to find out a solution and saw DRAM schematics. But I can't use capacitors in it. I want it to have only transistors and resistors.
Is it possible to reduce the amount of transistors required by replacing NAND gates or in some other way?

---

More details about the memory cell I'm using can be found [here](https://medium.com/coderscorner/what-exactly-is-in-a-1-bit-of-digital-memory-d5395f9001a6)

Comment: Standard SRAM cell is 6 transistors. You can find the schematics online.

Comment: You don't really design SRAM cells with NAND gates.  You design them with MOSFETS.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory

Comment: Is it possible to use Bipolar Junction Transistors ( BJT ) in place of MOSFETS ?